# Launch4j redirect to download java version

Tags: java, maven, launch4j

I used Launch4j plugin in my Java project with Maven. When I compile project to exe and run on Windows system where there is no Java installed, it redirects (automatically open web browser) to download Java but with 32-bit version. I want to redirect to download 64-bit newest version. Is it possible?

My plugin definition in Maven looks like

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.11</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>l4j-gui</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>launch4j</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <headerType>gui</headerType>
                <outfile>target/Project.exe</outfile>
                <jar>target/Project.jar</jar>
                <priority>high</priority>
                <errTitle>project</errTitle>
                <classPath>
                    <mainClass>com.project.Main</mainClass>
                    <preCp>libs/*.jar</preCp>
                </classPath>
                <jre>
                    <minVersion>1.8.0_101</minVersion>
                </jre>
                <icon>${basedir}/build-resources/win/application-${ENV}.ico</icon>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I tried to add in `<jar>...</jar>` the `<runtimeBits>64</runtimeBits>` and when run exe file pop up shows "The application requries a Java Runtime Environment 1.8.0_101 (64-bit)" and after click OK, it redirect to download 32-bit version, with page address `https://java.com/pl/download/`

**EDIT**

I tried also add in `<jar>...</jar>` the `<bundledJre64Bit>true</bundledJre64Bit>` but can not end compilation and return error as below

```
[INFO] --- launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7.11:launch4j (l4j-gui) @ stockbox-main ---
[INFO] Platform-specific work directory already exists: /Users/Arek/.m2/repository/net/sf/launch4j/launch4j/3.9
[ERROR] 
net.sf.launch4j.BuilderException: !Jre.bundled.64bit.invalid!
    at net.sf.launch4j.Builder.build(Builder.java:76)
    at com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j.Launch4jMojo.execute(Launch4jMojo.java:358)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: If you prefer 64-bit you probably want to add <runtimeBits>64</runtimeBits> or <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits> to your launch4j config, but IIRC that doesn't influence the download page that is shown (at least not a while back when I used launch4j).

Comment: I tried add in `<jar>...</jar>` to add `<runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>` and message is shown that need the java version (64-bit) but redirect to download 32-bit version.

Comment: Yeah, that was also the case a while back. I was hoping they fixed this in recent versions, but apparently not. Your only other option is to bundle your exe with a 64-bit jre.

Comment: I try bundled but can not compile with error - I edited my post.

Comment: That option is probably not what you are looking for. In the [documentation](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html) it says it's for using the available heap memory without a 32-bit limit and only works in combination with the HeapSize and HeapPercent options provided the found JRE is a bundled one.

Comment: Maybe you can add an answer yourself and select it as accepted answer instead of posting solution in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Before `<jre>...</jre>` just add `<downloadUrl>https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp</downloadUrl>` and that's it.

Redirect us to page when user can choose the java version according to system and which version must download by adding a `<runtimeBits>64</runtimeBits>` in `<jre>...` brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The details are provided here - See if it can help

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html

```
<bundledJre64Bit>true|false</bundledJre64Bit>
<bundledJreAsFallback>true|false</bundledJreAsFallback>
<runtimeBits>64|64/32|32/64|32</runtimeBits>
```

Comment: I tried only with `<runtimeBits>64</runtimeBits>` but it redirect to download 32-bit version